# How to stick div to bottom of table cell?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the orange div stick to the bottom of the table cell after inputting a number? Its a dice roll program displaying the amount of each outcome, and then changing the height of the div to match the outcome.

here is my code :

```js
window.onload = oppstart;

function oppstart() {
  document.getElementById("btnKnapp").onclick = animertDiv;
}

function animertDiv() {
  var hoyde6 = 0;
  var hoyde5 = 0;
  var hoyde4 = 0;
  var hoyde3 = 0;
  var hoyde2 = 0;
  var hoyde1 = 0;
  var antallKast = document.getElementById("kast").value
  for (var i = 0; i < antallKast; i++) {
    var terningkast = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    if (terningkast === 6) {
      hoyde6 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv6").style.height = hoyde6 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv6").innerHTML = hoyde6;
    }

    if (terningkast === 5) {
      hoyde5 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv5").style.height = hoyde5 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv5").innerHTML = hoyde5;
    }

    if (terningkast === 4) {
      hoyde4 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv4").style.height = hoyde4 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv4").innerHTML = hoyde4;
    }
    if (terningkast === 3) {
      hoyde3 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv3").style.height = hoyde3 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv3").innerHTML = hoyde3;
    }

    if (terningkast === 2) {
      hoyde2 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv2").style.height = hoyde2 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv2").innerHTML = hoyde2;
    }

    if (terningkast === 1) {
      hoyde1 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv1").style.height = hoyde1 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv1").innerHTML = hoyde1;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}

div {
  background-color: orange;
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: bottom;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: bottom;
}

p,
h3,
table,
th,
td {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div1>
  <h3>Skirv inn antall kast:</h3>
  <div1 class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control mr-1" id="kast" type="number">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnKnapp">Kast</button>
  </div1>
  <br> </br>
  <table>



    <tr>
      <td>Antall:</td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv1">
          <p id="txtDiv1"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv2">
          <p id="txtDiv2"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv3">
          <p id="txtDiv3"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv4">
          <p id="txtDiv4"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv5">
          <p id="txtDiv5"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv6">
          <p id="txtDiv6"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Terningkast:</td>
      <td>1:</td>
      <td>2:</td>
      <td>3:</td>
      <td>4:</td>
      <td>5:</td>
      <td>6:</td>

    </tr>


  </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with more relevant details. Specifically, please include any code that you already have. We aren't psychic and don't know which "orange divs" you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there... use `vertical-align: bottom;` instead of `text-align: bottom;`.

If you only want to align orange boxes at the the bottom, then make a specific css rule for that cells.

```js
window.onload = oppstart;

function oppstart() {
  document.getElementById("btnKnapp").onclick = animertDiv;
}

function animertDiv() {
  var hoyde6 = 0;
  var hoyde5 = 0;
  var hoyde4 = 0;
  var hoyde3 = 0;
  var hoyde2 = 0;
  var hoyde1 = 0;
  var antallKast = document.getElementById("kast").value
  for (var i = 0; i < antallKast; i++) {
    var terningkast = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    if (terningkast === 6) {
      hoyde6 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv6").style.height = hoyde6 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv6").innerHTML = hoyde6;
    }

    if (terningkast === 5) {
      hoyde5 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv5").style.height = hoyde5 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv5").innerHTML = hoyde5;
    }

    if (terningkast === 4) {
      hoyde4 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv4").style.height = hoyde4 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv4").innerHTML = hoyde4;
    }
    if (terningkast === 3) {
      hoyde3 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv3").style.height = hoyde3 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv3").innerHTML = hoyde3;
    }

    if (terningkast === 2) {
      hoyde2 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv2").style.height = hoyde2 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv2").innerHTML = hoyde2;
    }

    if (terningkast === 1) {
      hoyde1 += 1;
      document.getElementById("animertDiv1").style.height = hoyde1 + "px";
      document.getElementById("txtDiv1").innerHTML = hoyde1;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}

div {
  background-color: orange;
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: bottom;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

p,
h3,
table,
th,
td {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div1>
  <h3>Skirv inn antall kast:</h3>
  <div1 class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control mr-1" id="kast" type="number">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnKnapp">Kast</button>
  </div1>
  <br> </br>
  <table>



    <tr>
      <td>Antall:</td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv1">
          <p id="txtDiv1"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv2">
          <p id="txtDiv2"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv3">
          <p id="txtDiv3"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv4">
          <p id="txtDiv4"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv5">
          <p id="txtDiv5"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="animertDiv6">
          <p id="txtDiv6"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Terningkast:</td>
      <td>1:</td>
      <td>2:</td>
      <td>3:</td>
      <td>4:</td>
      <td>5:</td>
      <td>6:</td>

    </tr>


  </table>
```